# Add a layout dynamically in a layout already added dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm working on a android project and I'm trying to add a layout in another dynamically. The thing is the parent layout has been added dynamically as well...

The aim is to be able to use a template of a layout I can inflate several times, and to add in everyone of them another layout ( inflated from a xml file as well ).

In the main view, I'm adding my parent layout like this:

```
ViewGroup myLayout= (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scrollcontentcontainer);
View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.relative, myLayout, false);
myLayout.addView(layout);
```

One of the layout in my parent has an id "maincontainer" in which I want to add another layout. As his parent, it's a xml template I'm using several time.

```
 ViewGroup myLayout2= (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.maincontainer);
 View layout2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.somelayout, myLayout2, false);
 myLayout2.addView(layout2);
```

But this is not working.
Someone know how to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call findviewbyid on the view that you're looking in. Assuming this is in an activity of yours, just calling findviewbyid itself looks in the activity's layout set in setContentView. You're going to want to reference the specific "myLayout" when you call findViewById.

e.g. `ViewGroup myLayout2 = (ViewGroup) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.maincontainer);` This will search for the correct id in whatever xml file was inflated for myLayout2.